# How to query models where relationship is null in Strapi?

Tags: strapi

I have a model Category with a belongs to many relationship with itself:

- Category has many categories in `subcategories`
- Category belongs to one category in `supercategory`

When I query all categories I get the correct results:

- `strapi.services.category.find()`

When I query all subcategories I also get the correct results:

- `strapi.services.category.find({ supercategory_null: false })`

But when I query just supercategories it doesn't return any categories:

- `strapi.services.category.find({ supercategory_null: true })`

**Question**

How can I query just the categories that have no supercategory relationship?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
strapi.services.category.find({ supercategory_null: true },['category']);
```

Defination:
find(params, **populate**)

populate (array): you have to mention data you want populate e.g ["author", "author.name", "comment", "comment.content"]

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to use knex instead of the strapi api:

```
// Assuming your table name is `category`
const knex = strapi.connections.default;
const categories = await knex(`category`).select(`*`).where(`supercategory`, null);
```